# Spring Batch: Invalid Content was found starting with element 'batch:job'

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am getting a SAXParserException that  tag is invalid while trying to run the system.

Below is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd"
default-lazy-init="true">

<bean id="myItemProcessor" class="com.MyItemProcessor"/>
<bean id="myItemReader" class="com.MyItemReader"/>
<bean id="myItemWriter" class="com.MyItemWriter"/>

<batch:job id="helloWorldJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader" writer="myItemWriter"
                processor="myItemProcessor" commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Below is the exception that I keep getting:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'batch:job'.

Tried doing below but no luck:

1) Tried referring the xsd from the classpath

2) Tried modifying to the different point versions of the xsd. But still the issue remains the same.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
```

With

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
```

You missed one part of the declaration.

Comment: Tried modifying the xsd version to 2.2. still no luck.  it's the same exception.

Comment: Use like this then : http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd